# Log axis appearance in julia/Plots

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Here is a plot generated by julia's Plots library, using the `xaxis=:log` attribute:

[image]

The plot has evenly spaced tick marks, with labels like 10^0.25. This might be useful sometimes, but I find it a bit confusing for this plot, because most people don't know the value of 10^0.25 without looking it up.

I would prefer the x axis to have logarithmically spaced ticks, representing uniform intervals of the quantity on the x axis. Here's a quick example to show what I mean, generated using `semilogx` in Python's `matplotlib` lirary:

[image]

In this plot the x axis has ticks at x=1, x=2, x=3 etc., which I find more useful for the figures I'm generating. Can this be achieved in julia using Plots?

Comment: Cross ref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/appearance-of-log-axis-in-plots/24553/. If you ask the same question on multiple places it is good to include a cross reference, otherwise people may end up spending time on already answered questions.

Comment: @fredrikekre thanks. Normally I wouldn't cross post - in this case I found out that discourse.julialang.org existed just after posting here. If someone answers it in one forum I'll post a self-answer in the other one.

Answer (score 6):

As it has been told in the discourse topic, the default tick behavior (for most backends) is different than what you expected.

There is a way you can achieve the tick behaviour you want. You can manually set tick positions and tick labels through `xticks` (`yticks` or `zticks`) argument.

For example the following snippet will put ticks at equally spaced points as you wanted in your post.

```
x = 1:0.1:10;
y = rand(length(x));

plot(x, y, xscale=:log10, xticks=(1:10, 1:10))
```

The first element of the tuple is for the location of the ticks and the second is for the labels. Although I used a range object for labels, you can use array of `String`s or [`LaTeXStrings`](https://github.com/stevengj/LaTeXStrings.jl) etc.

You might also want to take a look at `minorticks` (`xminorticks` for your case) and `minorgrid` attributes in [the Julia Plots documentation.](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/)